# Core Graphics on a 2013 Mac Mini

Tags: macos, python, import

My python script imports from quartz.coregraphics. Is core graphics included on 2013 Mac Minis? I ask because import works on macbook pros running snow leopard and mavericks, but fails on a mini from early 2007 running OS 10.5. I don't want to buy a new mini without being sure that the script will work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You should be able to still use those packages on Mavericks (10.9) with the stock python (2.7.5)

I have not installed any python packages and both of the following commands work from the python interpreter:

```
import Quartz
import CoreGraphics
```

If your import statement is identical to what you listed in your question, then you may have to change the import statement, but those packages appear to still be there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This is a naive question, but I take it from your response that the presence or absence of core graphics is purely a function of OS (it doesn't matter whether it's a mac mini or a different machine)?

Comment: Right. The python modules are a bridge to the native OS X Core Graphics (aka Quartz) high level graphics API. As such they are subject to change if the underlying API gets deleted, but for most APIs there probably isn't anything to worry about. If there is a convenient Apple store you could stop by and check for yourself on one of their Mac Minis.